# How do I use IF formulas to display blanks or 0's dependent on data in other columns?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to get rows within column `G` in sheet `STATISTICS` to populate a `0` if there is no `L`'s to count in column `P` on sheet `TRADE LOG`.

However, if there are any `L`'s present in column `P` in sheet `TRADE LOG` then I would like these counted and a value displayed in the rows of column `G` on sheet `STATISTICS`.

The issue is that despite `COUNTIF` naturally producing a `0`I do not want a `0` present if there is **NO** data in the rows of column `E` on sheet `STATISTICS`

My current formula is as below:

`=COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"L",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))`

This is also all to be done within a date range as seen in the formula.

Could anyone suggest how I can achieve this? (VBA suggestions welcomed by if can be avoided then great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=if(COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"L",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28))=0,"",COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"L",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)))
```

Comment: Hi xanatos, thanks for your help although this formula does not produce a '0' when there is data in column E as desired.

Comment: What do you mean by in the rows of column E? Like anywhere in the whole column?

Comment: So when there is data in E16 then G16 should populate data using the COUNTIF. if there is nothing in E16 then G16 should come back blank.

Comment: =IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("E",ROW()))), "", COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"L",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)))

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IF Function combined with your COUNTIF function. In the IF Function you can then determine what the output should be. try this.

`=IF((COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"L",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)) = 0), "", COUNTIFS('TRADE LOG'!P:P,"L",'TRADE LOG'!B:B,">="&DATE(2021,2,1),'TRADE LOG'!B:B,"<="&DATE(2021,2,28)))`

this basically says that IF the value you are getting from COUNTIFS is Zero, then display a blank, "", value, otherwise display the value of the COUNTIF formula.
This wont work for everything that you want, but, if you want to change what is process if the condition is FALSE aka. the last part of that if function you can now set up the formula to do that for you.

I hope that helps, if I understood the question wrong please do not hesitate to come back and we will figure it out.

Comment: Hi Tolga thanks for your help, unfortunately, it comes back with 'there's a problem with your formula'.

Comment: Sorry. There was one too many brackets. try itt again :D I edited it.

Comment: We are getting there, the formula works although there is data in column E and it does not produce a '0' as desired.

Comment: Ok, so what kind of value do you want presented then if there is nothing in Column E? You can use a nested if function, that means basically adjusting the IF Function i wrote earlier and changing the initial condition to IF((COUNT('TRADE LOG'!E:E)>0),(IF..),(IF...). And so you can have IF functions within a IF Function. That should work. I wish I had your file in front of me so I could write it better. But I hope that works.

Comment: If there is no data in column E I would like it to return a blank. But as soon as data is entered into column E then I would like it to return the correct count using the COUNTIF. Thank you so much for the help, I understand it must be difficult trying to do this remotely.